# Remote Database Backup

Tags: mysql, backup, remote

I am attempting to find a reliable service that does remote MySQL Database Backup.

Price is no object, unless it's absurdly expensive. I understand this question doesn't really have an answer, and I apologize for that.

Iam just looking for suggestions on ways I can check out for myself.

If this isn't the right place for this question, you can, you know, insult me or something :)

Thank you!
Quintis

Comment: It's a good question. What OS locally? What edition (community, enterprise)? Prepared to try Percona XtraDB? Have local storage ready? Using InnoDB or MyISAM?

Comment: I'm using Windows 7 x64 Pro, the community (free) edition of MySQL (and workbench to manage it.) I've never heard of Percona XtraDB, but I'll check it out. We're planning on backing up to an external HD along with the remote backup plan, so yes. And finally, InnoDB. Thanks! :)

Comment: Are you stuck with Windows? Linux has way more & better tools. How much data are you storing?

Comment: Yeah, I'm very stuck with Windows. It's for my company, I don't see them making the switch. It's about 60 gigs and growing.

Comment: What's keeping you from finding a web hosting company that will allow you to rent a linux server?   From there you could open up a firewall access between the two machines and run a simple shell script to copy the backups from your Windows computer to your rented distant linux computer.  http://www.linode.com/ for example.

Comment: The answer to that would be 1. I'm new to database management in general, and 2. I've only ever used Windows, and therefore don't know the benefits of anything non-Windows.

Comment: Ok, so, I've set up a dual-booted Linux operating system (Ubuntu.) I'm new to Linux; does Ubuntu have the tools I need for this?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a consistent connection to the external source then setting up [replication](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replication.html) would be the way to go.  This way you ensure that all changes are automatically sent to the 'backup' (aka slave) server.  You could still run a regular backup script to dump the data to an external HD as a failsafe in case someone 'drops' all the tables int the database.  The book [High Performance MySQL](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596101718.do) is a good source of information on replication setups.

Comment: That looks great! I'll check it out, and if it works, I'll make sure to mark yours as the answer.